# What's the origin of characters flying through the night sky during the ED?

Tags: tropes, miss-kobayashis-dragon-maid, blend-s

Here it is in Miss Kobayashi's Dragon Maid:

[image: Miss Kobayashi's Dragon Maid ED]

and here it is in Blend S:

[image: Blend S ED]

Is Blend S just referencing Dragon Maid or is there an earlier instance of this?

Comment: I see multiple chibi-version girls flying in each picture. The pictures have a blue background. Other than that (from the pictures alone) I personally would not make a connection.  Maybe if I had seen *Blend S", a relation between the pictures would be more obvious.